# xcode-build unable to find real tvOS device from list of available destinations

Tags: appium, tvos, xcodebuild

I am trying to build the WebDriverAgent as provided by Appium for testing on my tvOS device. I noticed that the command was failing so I tried running myself to see what is going wrong. I get a very unusual error where it says "no available devices matched the request" however it then proceeds to list the exact device destination in list of available devices. What is going on here? Is this a bug with xcode-build? See output below. Xcode 13.4.1 Build version 13F100. appium-webdriver-agent version 1.3.5

```
2022-06-15 12:24:22.291 xcodebuild[46151:3561580] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionSentinelHostApplications for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionHosts.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
2022-06-15 12:24:22.291 xcodebuild[46151:3561580] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionPointIdentifierToBundleIdentifier for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionToBundleIdentifierMap.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
Command line invocation:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild build-for-testing test-without-building -project /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium-webdriveragent/WebDriverAgent.xcodeproj -scheme WebDriverAgentRunner_tvOS -destination "id=1dafa12122994bd53425e32165086f586c91c7ba,platform=tvOS,name=Living Room" GCC_TREAT_WARNINGS_AS_ERRORS=0 COMPILER_INDEX_STORE_ENABLE=NO

User defaults from command line:
    IDEPackageSupportUseBuiltinSCM = YES

Build settings from command line:
    COMPILER_INDEX_STORE_ENABLE = NO
    GCC_TREAT_WARNINGS_AS_ERRORS = 0

xcodebuild: error: Unable to find a destination matching the provided destination specifier:
        { platform:tvOS, id:1dafa12122994bd53425e32165086f586c91c7ba, name:Living Room }

    The requested device could not be found because no available devices matched the request.

    Available destinations for the "WebDriverAgentRunner_tvOS" scheme:
        { platform:tvOS, id:1dafa12122994bd53425e32165086f586c91c7ba, name:Living Room }
        { platform:tvOS Simulator, id:AB7961DA-7101-4F2E-AF7C-2AC7D796213C, OS:15.4, name:Apple TV }
        { platform:tvOS Simulator, id:10433C26-0EEB-4085-9EED-B94306F2B2E2, OS:15.4, name:Apple TV 4K (2nd generation) }
        { platform:tvOS Simulator, id:BE4D2F91-FE52-4E7C-81E5-A7A853162572, OS:15.4, name:Apple TV 4K (at 1080p) (2nd generation) }

    Ineligible destinations for the "WebDriverAgentRunner_tvOS" scheme:
        { platform:tvOS, id:dvtdevice-DVTiOSDevicePlaceholder-appletvos:placeholder, name:Any tvOS Device }
        { platform:tvOS Simulator, id:dvtdevice-DVTiOSDeviceSimulatorPlaceholder-appletvsimulator:placeholder, name:Any tvOS Simulator Device }
```